# How to receive screen resize message in curses?

Tags: ruby, x11, curses

I am using curses in Ruby to display data in two different windows. Since the code might run in a X11 terminal, I would like the curses window resize when the terminal resizes. Is there any way of doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
Signal.trap("SIGWINCH") do
   ...
end
```